# Error after creating executable Pygame with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, segmentation-fault, pygame, pyinstaller

So my pygame script in python works perfectly, so I decided to try to bundle the program in order to distribute it, using [Pyinstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html). I compiled and ran Pyinstaller just as directed:

```
sudo pip install pyinstaller
pyinstaller Loop.py
```

It worked fine. Then I ran the generated executable file to see it in action:

```
cd /dist/Loop/
./Loop
```

The result, was this:

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Not a single line of Loop.py seems to be executed, since the first lines after importing packages is to open a new window (which didn't happen). With a little googling, it seems the only recommended solution is to debug the code to find where the segmentation took place. However, that doesn't make sense since the code works perfectly fine on its own, it only does this after using pyinstaller. I even entered a python shell in the same directory as the Loop executable, and verified that there is no problem in importing pygame.

At any rate, I'm just looking for a way to bundle the python project. Of course, if you know any better way to bundle a python project for distribution (using Python 2.7 on Ubuntu 16) I'd be happy to check it out :)

**Edit**

I created a version of my code which is as simplified as possible, in order to focus on the main issue (and of course to prove that the problem is reproducible). Here is the main program (`Loop.py`):

```
from Car import*

vehicle = Car()


def display_all(main_surface, display_list):
    main_surface.fill((0, 100, 100))
    for element in display_list:
        element.display(main_surface)


def update_all(update_list):
    for element in update_list:
        element.update()


running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            None

    key = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    to_update = [vehicle]
    to_display = [vehicle]

    update_all(to_update)
    display_all(main_s, to_display)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

And here is `Car.py`:

```
from Startup import*


class Car:
    def __init__(self):
        self.body = pygame.image.load("Images//Body//Grey.png")
        self.wheels = pygame.image.load("Images//Wheels//Black.png")
        self.rect = self.body.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = width/2
        self.rect.y = height/2
        self.rect.center = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
        self.angle = 0
        self.move_x = 0
        self.move_y = 0

    def display(self, main_surface):
        temp_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.body, self.angle)
        main_surface.blit(temp_image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        temp_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.wheels, self.angle)
        main_surface.blit(temp_image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

    def update(self):
        self.move_x = 0
        self.move_y = 0
```

And here is `Startup.py`:

```
import pygame
import math
pygame.font.init()

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 20)

pygame.init()
width = 1000
height = 600
main_s = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
```

**Edit (again)**

I just tried `py2app` as suggested in the comment, and it doesn't seem to work. As seen in [the only documentation](https://py2app.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#) I can find, the intention is to be run on MacOS. As clearly stated above, I am using Ubuntu 16, and that is the architecture I am coding on. When I completed the tutorial linked above, I had no complications, and proceeded to execute the file:

```
./dist/Loop.app/Contents/MacOS/Loop
```

And I promptly got the error:

```
bash: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

This seems to indicate it is not meant for my computer.

Do you have any idea if there is a version that works for Ubuntu? or if there is another solution?

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Are you using the latest version of PyInstaller? You should include a preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code to reproduce the problem, then we can try to help.

Comment: I showed exactly how I installed PyInstaller in the question, so yes I do have the latest version, running `pyinstaller -v` returns 3.3.1

Comment: Code sample added. Now you can run exactly what I did.

Comment: Possibly related: [kivy/kivy#2034](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/2034) and [kivy/kivy#3917](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/3917), but doesn't look like they found a good solution for this... Bug report in Pyinstaller [pyinstaller/pyinstaller#1805](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1805) didn't go anywhere either... One of the reporters mentioned that py2app worked for him, so maybe try that see if it works for you?

Comment: ok, but py2app seems to only be for MacOS? I just tried it on my Ubuntu 16 (as I stated in the original question) and I got `bash: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error` which indicates it is made for a different architecture than my machine.

Comment: Is there no way to bundle a python script as an executable???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for providing a suitable example, it's helped me to identify the culprit:

```
font = pygame.font.SysFont("", 20)
```

If you disable that line, you should be able to build and run your executable. This is easy to test as `font` isn't used in your example.

There seems to be a problem searching for a non-existent font, if you change the name to something that's probably available like `Arial`, or include a list as the [documentation states](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.SysFont). Or you can specify a font from those available, e.g. `pygame.font.get_fonts()[0]`.

Here's a modified example that moves the car towards wherever you click the mouse:

```
import pygame
import math

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
all_fonts = pygame.font.get_fonts()
print(all_fonts)
font = pygame.font.SysFont(all_fonts[0], 20) # just use the first font.
#font = pygame.font.SysFont("Arial, couriernewm", 20)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

width = 1000
height = 600
main_s = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

class Car(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """Sprite with self drawn images"""
    def __init__(self, speed=5):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((40,30)).convert_alpha()  # sprites need an 'image'
        self.image.fill((0,0,0,0)) # make transparent
        pygame.draw.rect(self.image, (111,111,111), (0,5, 40, 15)) # draw the body
        for center in [(5,5), (35,5), (5,20), (35, 20)]:  # draw four wheels
            pygame.draw.circle(self.image, (0,0,0), center, 5)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = width/2
        self.rect.y = height/2
        self.rect.center = self.rect.x, self.rect.y
        self.angle = 0
        self.move_x = 0
        self.move_y = 0
        self.speed = speed
        self.destination = self.rect.center

    def update(self, pos=None):
        if pos:
            #set new destination
            self.destination = pos
        else:
        # move towards destination at speed
            xd = self.destination[0] - self.rect.center[0]
            if xd < 0:
                xd = max(xd, -self.speed)
            else:
                xd = min(xd, self.speed)
            yd = self.destination[1] - self.rect.center[1]
            if yd < 0:
               yd = max(yd, -self.speed)
            else:
                yd = min(yd, self.speed)
            self.rect.center = (self.rect.center[0] + xd, self.rect.center[1] + yd)


# create a sprite group to store cars
slow_car = Car()
vehicles = pygame.sprite.Group(slow_car)

running = True
#main loop
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            pass
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # move to position
            vehicles.update(event.pos)
    # update sprites
    vehicles.update()

    # clear surface
    main_s.fill((0, 100, 100))

    #draw sprites
    vehicles.draw(main_s)

    # update display
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
pygame.quit()
```

Note: Unfortunately this isn't running on a Mac, so I can't guarantee it'll work. I did see application failures when launching the executable.

Comment: Is there any way to find out what fonts are available?

Comment: The function [pygame.font.get_fonts()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.get_fonts) will return a list of fonts, so you can print that, or select one from that list. I used the first available one, `all_fonts[0]` from the example code. You may be able to explicitly bundle fonts with your application, but I've not tried that.